# Failed opening required file on live server

Tags: php, linux

I have a file called Utilities.php stored in a folder called SRC, this folder contains a folder called DB. DB has a file called classes.php. So this is the structure:

```
SRC/
  DB/
  classes.php
utilities.php
```

Now, I am want to require classes.php in utilities.php, I am doing this locally and it works:

```
require_once 'src/db/classes.php';
```

But when I move the project to a live server (AWS), I get this error:

```
Failed opening required 'src/db/classes.php'
```

Please how do I fix this?

Comment: Either the file structure is different or you have a permissions issue.  Do you have access to the command line on the remote?  Then you could verify the directory structure and/or `ls -al` to see permissions.

Comment: Check the permission of whole project and its sub directory and files.

Comment: On *nix systems, file and directory names are case sensitive, so if your folders are in upper case then you have to use `require_once 'SRC/DB/classes.php';`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps on AWS you script has different current directory. Try using with `__DIR__` const:

```
require __DIR__ . '/src/db/classes.php';
```